# How to check all check boxes on user control after runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, user-controls

I have no idea if this is possible, but I am making a system where for each item in a list it will parse info and make a user control with the info. I would like to know how or if I should even use a user control for this. I do not want to use a data grid(if possible). My goal is to find a way to enable all the check boxes (1 per user control) with a click of a button after runtime. Possibly know how to also set a value on the user control would be cool too.

[this is a example of the user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2quFX.png)

[this is what the user controls look like after the while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9wQm.png)

My thought on how to fix this is to make a list of all the user controls, but I cant figure out how to find the check box and check it.

This is my code on creating the user controls.

```cs
                   foreach (var user in get.users)
                    {                     
                        Users.Account account = new Users.Account(); //user control creator
                        account.name.Content = user.User.Username;   //set the content to the name
                        account.NUMBER = i;                          //Uid
                        this.account_list.Children.Add(account);     //crates a usercontrol in a stack panel
                        accounters.Add(account);                     //my idea on a List<UserControl>
                        i++;
                    }
```

Any help would be Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Regardless whether you declare a UserControl or not, you should not create it in code behind. Use an ItemsControl with the UserControl (or something else) in its ItemTemplate, and bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of user item objects. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Probably just declare a set of controls including the CheckBox in the DataTemplate, and bind the CheckBox's IsChecked property to a property of your user class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better create control through ItemsControl, not in code behind

xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

viewmodel

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class WpfTestVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users { get; } = new ObservableCollection<UserModel> {new UserModel { Name = "1"}, new UserModel { Name = "2" } };
}
```

Comment: Be aware that your WpfTestVm implements INotifyPropertyChanged without reason. The PropertyChanged event is never fired.

Comment: @Clemens ok, here we don't need to have this stuff, thanks, I've deleted it.

Comment: @Saussy if my answer was helpful for you you can mark it as Accepted Answer

Comment: thank you for this, It should help me go in the right direction.